# Is there a splitting field for multivariate polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, galois-theory

Let $f(X,Y) = X^2 + Y^2 - c$.  Does there exist a field $F$ such that $f(X,Y) = \prod_{i=1}^n(a_1^i X + a_2^i Y + a_3^i)$, where $a^i$'s are in $F$?

Comment: Read about this. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puiseux_series

Comment: If you are over a field of characteristic 2, then $(X^2+Y^2-c^2)=(X+Y-c)^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The zero locus of a product like
$$
\prod_{i=1}^n(a_1^iX+a_2^iY+a_3^i)
$$
is the union of the lines
$$
a_1^iX+a_2^iY+a_3^i=0.
$$
On the other hand the zero locus of $X^2+Y^2-a$ is a circle of radius $\sqrt a$. A circle is not a union of lines no matter how you turn the coordinates.

---

You can apply the theory of splitting fields and such, but then you can only have a single variable. The other variables must be included into the field!
So you can do the following. Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(X)$ be the field of rational functions of the variable $X$. You can view $f$ as a quadratic polynomial in the ring $K[Y]$. Then $f$ has a splitting field
$$K_f=K[\sqrt{c-X^2}],$$
i.e. you need to adjoin a square root of an element of $K$.

Comment: Could the solution set to a linear equation over some other unknown algebraic structure contain the solution set of a nonlinear polynomial in the field that *it's* over?

Comment: An interesting question, @EnjoysMath. I would say, "NO!" to that as well. The solution set of a linear equation over that bigger field $F$ is a coset of a vector space subspace of $F^n$. When we intersect that with the subset $E^n$ with coefficients in the smaller field $E$, the intersection will be a coset of a linear subspace, too. Possibly the dimension will go down, when we form the intersection, but it cannot go up.

Comment: I don't think $(x_0, y_0) + V$ (a coset in $F^2$) is necessarily a coset in $\mathbb{R^2}$ when intersected with it.

Comment: If $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)\in ((x_0,y_0)+V)\cap\mathbb{Q}^2$, then the points on the line connecting $(x_1,y_1)$ to $(x_2,y_2)$ inside $\mathbb{Q}^2$ will also be in the intersection. It follows that the intersection is the coset $(x_1,y_1)+U$, where $U$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{Q}^2$.

Comment: The line connecting the two points is given by $l(t) = (x_1, y_1)(1-t) + (x_2, y_2)t$ for real $t$.  Substituting in the formulas for their membership in $(x_0,y_0)+V$ gives a $t(x_0, y_0)$, so points of $l(t)$ are not necessarily in the coset.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean? The assumption was that $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ are in $(x_0,y_0)+V$. So if $(x_i,y_i)=(x_0,y_0)+v_i$ for $i=1,2$, then surely
$$
\ell(t)=(x_0,y_0)+(1-t)v_1+tv_2,
$$ and $(1-t)v_1+tv_2\in V$, because $V$ is vector space over a field containing $t$?

Comment: I did it on paper and get that a point on the line is in the coset $t(x_0, y_0) + V$, ie different from the original coset.

Comment: It's not in the coset but $l(t)/t$ is.

Comment: But we were given that both $\ell(0)$ and $\ell(1)$ are in the coset! Are you saying that if $v_1$ and $v_2$ are in $V$, it is possible that $(1-t)v_1+tv_2$ is not in $V$?

Comment: You're right!  My bad...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, although probably not in the way you'd like it. If you put $F={\bf Q}(X,Y)$, then $f(X,Y)\in F$, and your condition is trivially satisfied.

For a more meaningful question, you could ask if there is a field $F$ of characteristic $0$ such that $X,Y$ are transcendent over $F$ and $f$ factors into linear terms over $F[X,Y]$. In which case, Jyrki's answer is probably the right way to see it.

A different way to show that it's not possible for $c\neq 0$ is by direct calculation, for example with two linear terms (other cases we can rule out by degree considerations):

1. Suppose that it is otherwise and $X^2+Y^2-c=(a_1X+b_1Y+c_1)(a_2X+b_2Y+c_2)$. This means that $a_1a_2=b_1b_2=1,c_1c_2=-c$ etc.
2. Without loss of generality $a_1=1$ (we can multiply the second linear term by $a_1$ and the first by $a_1^{-1}$). Then $a_2=a_1^{-1}=1$ (by examining the $X^2$  term).
3. Furthermore if we look at $XY$ term, we get that $a_1b_2+b_1a_2=b_1+b_2=0$, and by $Y^2$ term $b_1\neq 0$.
4. Now, we look at $X$ and $Y$ terms. They give us $a_1c_2+c_1a_2=c_1+c_2=0$ and $(b_1c_2+c_1b_2)=b_1(c_2-c_1)=0$. This implies that $2c_1=0$, so because characteristic is not $2$, $c_1=c_2=0$ and $c=0$. This is indeed possible, as we have $X^2+Y^2=(X+iY)(X-iY)$.

The same proof will work for any field of characteristic $\neq 2$. In characteristic $2$, we have $X^2+Y^2-c=(X+Y+\sqrt c)^2$.

Comment: Please see my comment below Jyrki's.  The rational solutions two a linear equation in $F^2$ are not necessarily a linear coset in $\mathbb{Q}^2$.

Comment: @EnjoysMath: I've added an elementary proof.

Comment: What if we lift the restriction that the polynomial must equal the product of linear factors on all of $F^2$.  Then is it possible?

Comment: @EnjoysMath: I don't really understand what you're asking about. Care to explain more?

Comment: A linear factoring $g(X,Y)$ over $F^2$ such that $g(X,Y) = f(X,Y)$ on all of $\mathbb{Q}$ but not necessarily on all of $F^2$.  Is that not helpful to us for some reason?

Comment: @EnjoysMath: this doesn't help: a polynomial is determined by its values on rational numbers (or even integers, or any infinite set).